# iPhone app rejection 17.2: app requires users sign in with their Facebook accounts

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, authentication, appstore-approval

I followed the login instructions for my native iOS app here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/

I have everything facebook in the AppDelegate in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"xyzabc" andDelegate:self];
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] 
    && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
    facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
}


if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
    NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                            @"publish_stream", 
                            nil];
    [facebook authorize:permissions];

}
```

The problem is that my app opens and I require people to be logged in to facebook to use the features in my app.  Apple rejected me saying the Facebook feature should be optional rather than forced (listed under rejection reason 17.2).

I was just wondering if I can keep most everything in the app delegate, but put the

```
    if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
        NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                @"publish_stream", 
                                nil];
        [facebook authorize:permissions];
}
```

somewhere else (like when a login to facebook button is pressed).  If this is the case, should the facebook documentation be updated so no one else gets rejected?  Or maybe I missed something where I can keep that in the app delegate, but call something else to make login optional?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Is the only purpose of your application to post to Facebook? If not, people like myself who have no Facebook account won't be able to use the non-Facebook portions if you make a login mandatory. You should only prompt to login to Facebook when someone goes to access Facebook-based features. Everything else should still be accessible before that point.

Comment: No, my app has other features other than posting to Facebook.  I didn't like the fact that the user was forced to log in to facebook either, so I completely understand the rejection.  I thought I followed the instructions and that facebook must want login to be that way.  I just wanted to know how other people made login optional, since the instructions didn't seem to show that.  I also wanted to bring attention to it here to help other people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did to solve this is I moved all the Facebook code from -applicationDidFinishLaunching to a custom method -createFBInstance that I called from a UIViewController whenever a UIButton was pressed so now the user only logs in to Facebook when a button is clicked and the app works great!  Just make sure you only use the methods from the FBSessionDelegate inside your delegate I could never make it work in any other class.  I also opened up the login web page in a web view inside the app so it looks much nicer.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it will be rejected. 17.2 says **Apps that require users to share personal information, such as email address and date of birth,
in order to function will be rejected.** There is no way for users to use your application until they have facebook account. Instead I suggest you keep it optional like login with facebook/Google and have your application's own registration procedure.

Comment: I agree that facebook should be optional.  The main point of my post was that I followed the instructions and my app was rejected.

Comment: (comment continued) The instructions seem to be written in a way that makes facebook NOT optional.  So, I posted 1) to see if there was something I missed in the instructions, 2) to bring light to the fact that the directions may not be accurate and could cause rejection to help others out, and 3) to see what other people's opinions were about the best way to handle facebook login.  It helps to make posts and get more points, since I'm new to this:) Thanks for trying to help though... did anyone tell you, you look like Steve Jobs?;-)

Comment: Yeah. He appointed me to help iOS developers before he went to heaven.. ;-)