# App got rejected only using Facebook as login option?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-login

**I got following email from apple**

> 1.0.1 Binary Rejected June 16, 2015 
>   17.2 Details We noticed that your app uses Facebook login for authentication purposes but does not include account-based features
>   offered

**I got following attachment**

> From Apple
>   17.2 - Apps that require users to share personal information, such as email address and date of birth, in order to function will be rejected
>   17.2 Details
>
> We noticed that your app uses Facebook login for authentication
>   purposes but does not include account-based features offered by that
>   site, which is not allowed on the App Store.
>
> Next Steps
>
> Please modify your app to include account-based features of that
>   social network or use your own authentication mechanism.

what is the reason behinds it.
 I have study the following links

https://www.parse.com/questions/app-rejected-facebook-login-doesnt-complete

[App got rejected because only using Facebook as login option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17455605/app-got-rejected-because-only-using-facebook-as-login-option)

[Apple rejected app 10.6 because Facebook opens Safari to login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27918011/apple-rejected-app-10-6-because-facebook-opens-safari-to-login)

Comment: Have you included the Facebook account from settings of iPhone? I guess you are now just allow login from iPhone browser and not fetching Facebook information from settings of iPhone.

Comment: does that make difference

Comment: yes, I have a app on AppStore with just Facebook login and I have included this in that app. Here is the app link: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/memorop/id900844724?ls=1&mt=8

I think this is the only reason. Please include this and resubmit the app.

Comment: what should i include can u please tell me

Comment: when you tap on say(login with Facebook), check if Facebook account is configured in settings of your iPhone. If configured, then use Facebook information from there. Otherwise, go for browser Facebook login(or what you are doing right now in your app). Make sense?

Comment: **the rejection is straightforward**. that is typical data-phising. the application must be able to be used without any sign-up, or if you like it better: *anonymously*; so make the Facebook-login _optional_ and let the users use your app without login and your app will pass the review.

Comment: yes i m trying to reconstruct with next login option and facebook as optional any way thanks for answer

Comment: hey nestle, did you walk way from the rejection yet? and how?

Answer (score 4):

Apple review Guidelines says [here](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#data-collection-and-storage)

> **5.1.1 Data Collection and Storage**
>
> (ii) If your app doesn’t include significant account-based features,
>   let people use it without a log-in. Apps may not require users to
>   enter personal information to function, except when directly relevant
>   to the core functionality of the app or required by law. If your core
>   app functionality is not related to a specific social network (e.g.
>   Facebook, WeChat, Weibo, Twitter, etc.), you must provide access
>   without a login or via another mechanism. Pulling basic profile
>   information, sharing to the social network, or inviting friends to use
>   the app are not considered core app functionality.

I've a published app that has an **optional** login feature without any "account-based features".

**I think providing a "continue as guest" option will fix the issue.**

Answer (score 2):

This means that your app didn't implement another feature of Facebook anywhere else in your application, if you're asking for explanation. If you make an app that just has Facebook's Log-in API, but nothing else, then your app will be rejected. Find another feature of Facebook (such as sharing or invites) that you can implement somewhere in your application, and try again.

Comment: I have implemented share features too

Comment: Not sure, then. Make sure you're also following Facebook's Platform Guidelines as well as Apple's Guidelines. You might be missing something from that.

Comment: what might it be can u please explain me .. I seriously need the help

Comment: I don't know what it is; you simply posted the e-mail you got back from Apple after you tried to submit your app. This isn't even a question about coding.

Comment: Try replying back to the reviewer. They might have overlooked your submission's sharing functionality.

Comment: ok i will reply but before that i want to research what is the  problem behind that so

Comment: @nischalhada Explain to Apple team that your app also have Facebook sharing feature and from where it can be access in your app. My app was also rejected but after discussing with Apple they told me to again submitt the app with demo account. Don't forget to mention all this in note while you submitt your app.

Comment: i have up vote for ur efforts hopes to get same on my questions too

Answer (score 2):

A few possible steps you can take:

- Ask App Store review people for clarification. Wait until you didn’t
  get a response from them
- You can make user registration optional or only prompt for it where
  it actually requires

Try it.

Comment: i have up vote for ur efforts hopes to get same on my questions too

Answer (score 1):

Add note, while submitting app,the purpose of using Facebook login in resolution center without uploading new build it will be approve.
If still you face any issue then add some functionality of user login.
For Ex: Use of facebook login is for keeping all records of user in our database and also explain a bit about your app functionality why you use login feature.Hope it will help
Also check
[iPhone app rejection 17.2: app requires users sign in with their Facebook accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728585/iphone-app-rejection-17-2-app-requires-users-sign-in-with-their-facebook-accoun?rq=1)

Comment: Ok i will try that out

Comment: i have up vote for ur efforts hopes to get same on my questions too